# Error: GET http://mywebsite.com/tmp/highchart_oqoCdS 403 (Forbidden)

Tags: php, jquery, json, highcharts

### The server seems pretty unhappy trying to work with the jQuery min file. The error that is being reported is:

```
GET http://mywebsite.com/tmp/highchart_C6MyqK 403 (Forbidden) 
                                                              jquery.min.js:2
```

The highchart_C6MyqK is a json file that is created with a random name from the **code below**.  My eventual goal is to create this Highstock chart:

> http://www.highcharts.com/stock/demo/compare

Though when loading the page, it stays blank with the **forbidden error**. I have tried this code on two different server hosts with the same error.

---

Here is my code. The first half is getting the data, the second half is creating the graph.

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/stock/highstock.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/stock/modules/exporting.js"></script>
```

---

```
<?php
//Find all .csv files
$files = glob('*.csv');
$dates = array();
for($i=0;$i<count($files);$i++){
    $str = substr($files[$i],-14, -4);
    $dates[] = $str;
}
sort($dates);

//Get data from csv files
$tmpFile = tempnam('tmp/','highchart_');
$out = fopen($tmpFile, "w");
fputs($out, '[');
for($i=0;$i<count($files);$i++){
    if (($handle = fopen($files[$i], "r")) !== FALSE) {
        while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ',')) !== FALSE) {
            $timestamp = strtotime($data[0].' '.$data[1]);
            fputs($out, '['.(int)$timestamp.','.(float)$data[2].','.
            (float)$data[3].','.(float)$data[4].','.(float)$data[5].','.
            (float)$data[12].','.(float)$data[13].']');
        }
        fclose($handle);
    }
}
fputs($out, ']');
fclose($out);
?>
```

---

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
var seriesOptions = [],
    yAxisOptions = [],
    seriesCounter = 0,
    names = ['CBS min', 'CBS max', 'CBS avg. peak min', 'CBS avg. peak max', 'LKFS', 'LRA' ],
    colors = Highcharts.getOptions().colors;

$.each(names, function(i, name) {

    $.getJSON('<? echo $tmpFile ?>',    function(data) {

        seriesOptions[i] = {
            name: name,
            data: data
        };

        seriesCounter++;

        if (seriesCounter == names.length) {
            createChart();
        }
    });
});



// create the chart when all data is loaded
function createChart() {

    $('#container').highcharts('StockChart', {
        chart: {
        },

        rangeSelector: {
            selected: 4
        },

        yAxis: {
            labels: {
                formatter: function() {
                    return (this.value > 0 ? '+' : '') + this.value + '%';
                }
            },
            plotLines: [{
                value: 0,
                width: 2,
                color: 'silver'
            }]
        },
        
        plotOptions: {
            series: {
                compare: 'percent'
            }
        },
        
        tooltip: {
            pointFormat: '<span style="color:{series.color}">{series.name}</span>: <b>{point.y}</b> ({point.change}%)<br/>',
            valueDecimals: 2
        },
        
        series: seriesOptions
    });
}

});
</script>
```

---

```
<div id="container" style="height: 500px; min-width: 600px"></div>
```

Thanks in advance for your insight!

Comment: Check the file permissions on the json file. It must be readable by the webserver.

Comment: The user can read and write.

Comment: It must not only be readable by the web server, it must be readable by everyone, since JavaScript is executed client side and not server side.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is probably related to the permissions of the JSON file you created. Check if it has read permissions (for everyone, not only the file's owner).

If not (which is probably the case), put this at the end of your PHP function creating the file, under `fclose($out)`:

```
chmod($tmpFile, 0644); # Read/write for file owner, read for everyone else
```

It needs to be readable by everyone since JavaScript is executed **client-side** and not server-side.

Comment: Got: `Warning: chmod() expects parameter 1 to be a valid path`. I think I may have put the code in the wrong part of the function.  Which line should I put it under?

Comment: Oh sorry, I got that wrong. It should be the path to the file (`$tmpFile`). You should put the code under the `fclose($out)` line. Updating my answer.

Comment: Great! That got rid of the error.  But the graph is still not loading. I must have my graphing api documentation wrong.  Do you happen to know anything about Highstock?

Comment: Perfect. As much as I'd like to help, I don't know anything about Highstock, sorry...

Comment: Haha, I will repost and reword the question with different tags.  Thanks for your help! I had been stumped for a while with this one.